# twitter embedded code into custom html tag with php

Tags: php, twitter

How can we change twitter embed code

```
(start blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en">******* end blockquote)
```

into custom twitter code

```
(start twitter id="791581699024879616" end twitter tag)
```

using PHP?

Comment: i don't think this is possible

Comment: @Blueblazer172,  can we retrieve Url of the status?